# Extracting, and then use in a comparison, the object type within a vector appropriately. c++

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I have a vector of pointers to vehicles which contains vehicles like cars, lorries, motorcycles. These vehicles have positions associated with them and these positions are tracked and drawn using drawPoint() in QT. I would like to know how to implement an alternative way of checking the object type of each element, i.e, without using typeid.

```
for (unsigned int jV = 0; jV < fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getNVehiclesinLane(); jV++)
   {
       //QPainter painter(this); //already done outside loop
       QPen pointpenv(Qt::red);
       pointpenv.setWidth(5);
       QPen pointpenC(Qt::blue); // For a Car
       pointpenC.setWidth(5);
       QPen pointpenL(Qt::green); // For a Lorry
       pointpenL.setWidth(5);
       QPen pointpenM(Qt::yellow); // For a Motorcycle
       pointpenM.setWidth(5);

       double position = fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV)->getPosition();

       if(typeid(fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV)) == typeid(Car*)){painter.setPen(pointpenC);}
       else if(typeid(fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV)) == typeid(Lorry*)){painter.setPen(pointpenL);}
       else if(typeid(fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV)) == typeid(Motorcycle*)){painter.setPen(pointpenM);}

       painter.drawPoint(((iLane * (width()/fRoadDisp->getNLanes())) + width()/(2 *   fRoadDisp->getNLanes())), position * height()/300);
   }
```

The above loops over all the vehicles in a vector of pointers to vehicles and just makes available different coloured pens for different vehicles, and, depending on which type of vehicle is being drawn, I would like the appropriate pen to be activated.

Currently, any points just appear white. A possible solution (I have been told) is to use static public variables, but I am not sure how to implement this in place of typeid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well usually that is a candidate to use polymorphism, since you already seem to have different classes for your vehicles, why not use them to get the color? You can define a `getColor()` method in your Vehicle base cass and have all sub classes return a different color, so no need to do a typeid or switch etc.

Comment: @xander that couples `Vehicle` to the drawing code. If the set of Vehicle types is mostly static, then a `VehicleVisitor` is probably better than adding unrelated properties to `Vehicle`

Comment: "I have a vector of pointers":  Please smart pointer, please smart pointer, please smart pointer.....

Comment: @UKMonkey Qt is really bad in that regard, transferring ownership around in raw pointers. It's defensible for "GUI hierachy that needs to be compatible with C++98", but leaks out into other usage :(

Comment: @Caleth Agreed, but you can still have a parallel hierarchy of classes for drawing purposes. Something like `QtVehicle`, `QtCar` etc.

Comment: @Caleth yes and no - where Qt doesn't take ownership of the object, there's no reason to have smart pointers and the UI members of the same object - this will allow QT to live in it's happy raw pointer world while you're happy in the knowledge that the UI container will stop any memory leaks.

Comment: @UKMonkey I think we agree on good practice, I was commenting that Qt's use of raw pointers can be a bad influence on other code

Comment: @Caleth and that I think we also agree on!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the approach suggested by vahancho, but, given the necessary refactoring, I wouldn't add an enum to the scene and directly give a penColor property to  abstract Vehicle's, to avoid inspecting their type:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    virtual QColor penColor() const { return Qt::red; }
};
class Car : public Vehicle
{
  public:
  QColor penColor() const { return Qt::blue; }
};
```

So you pick the right pen this way:

```
painter.setPen(QPen(fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV).penColor()));
```

No `if`'s and no `std::map` needed.

However, if you think the penColor property doesn't exactly belong to a Vehicle, you can use a separate class to hold drawing information:

```
struct DrawingInfo
{
    DrawingInfo() : penColor(Qt::red), penWidth(5){}
    DrawingInfo(QColor c) : penColor(c), penWidth(5){}
    DrawingInfo(QColor c, int w) : penColor(c), penWidth(w){}

    QColor penColor;
    int penWidth;
};
```

and give a Vehicle, and its derived classes, an instance of it:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    DrawingInfo drawingInfo() const { return _drawingInfo; }
protected:
    DrawingInfo _drawingInfo;
};
class Car : public Vehicle
{
public:
    Car()
    {
        _drawingInfo.penColor = Qt::blue;
    }
};
```

This time, you can select the right pen this way:

```
Vehicle v = fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV);
QPen pen(v.drawingInfo().penColor);
pen.setWidth(v.drawingInfo().penWidth);
painter.setPen(pen);
```

Comment: This approach is simpler if coloring is the only reason why application needs to know the type of the vehicle.

Comment: However it is superlinearly less simple the more things need to distinguish types of vehicles

Comment: @vahancho you're perfectly right, I edited the answer to smooth the issue.

Comment: @Caleth I think there are already many ways to do that (typeid, dynamic_cast<>, and while we're talking Qt, here, the meta object system provides a QMetaObject::className() which could fit that need).

Comment: *if you think the penColor property doesn't exactly belong to a Vehicle* - Or just store the car color as a `QColor` rather than storing the pen, then pass that to your DrawingInfo class.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, kind of yes. One could ask oneself if "car color" is related to "drawing a point that represent a car on the map" or "showing the actual car color".

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o, perhaps but for me, storing the pen in the Vehicle class is coupling the functionality of the class with how it's drawn. Not great, if we want to change the renderer at a later stage, with one that doesn't use QPen; e.g. Using OpenGL.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Note that the `penColor()` function in your Vehicle class should not be declared as virtual, since the implementation will likely not change in derived classes.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, ah, I see your concern, now, sorry. But I'm returning QColor, up there, not QPen. Anyway, given your concern, it would be better return a neutral representation of a colour, like, say, a 32 bit  integer representing RGBA or such.

Comment: @p-a-o-l-o Returning `QColor` is irrelevant to declaring the function as virtual.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight it was the answer to your other comment. About virtual, I don't understand how could it possibly work, without.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160607/discussion-between-thedarkknight-and-p-a-o-l-o).

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem in the following way:

1. Declare an abstract class `Vehicle`, such ass:

   ```
   class Vehicle
   {
   public:
     enum Type
     {
       Car,
       Lorry
     }    
     virtual Type getType() const = 0;
   };
   ```
2. Derive all vehicle classes from this `Vehicle` class:

   ```
   class Car : public Vehicle
   {
     public:
     Type getType() const override { return Vehicle::Car; }
   };
   ```

etc.

3. In your drawing routines you will need to just:

   ```
   if (fRoadDisp->getCurrentLane(iLane)->getCurrentVehicle(jV)->getType == Vehicle::Car)
   {
     painter.setPen(pointpenC);
   }
   ```

Comment: What about a `std::map<Vehicle::Type, QPen>` instead of an if chain?

Comment: Yeah, that would be also a good approach. However the question was about objects identification.

Answer (score 0):

I would add the colour to the vehicle class

```
class Vehicle : public QObject
{
    public:
       Vehicle(QColor colour);
       QColor Colour() const;

    private:
        QColor m_vehicleColour;
};
```

This makes more sense than storing the actual QPen, which is not a property of a vehicle.

> I would like to know how to implement an alternative way of checking the object type of each element, i.e, without using typeid.

If your vehicles are QObjects, it should be noted that you can use [QMetaObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) to retrieve a vehicle's type

Assuming we've derived Car from Vehicle

```
Vehicle* pCar = new Car(Qt::red);
if(pCar->metaObject() == "Car")
{
    // This instance of vehicle is a car
}
```

Of-course, it's better not to have *if(type) then...*

So, the renderer can now create a QPen with the right color

```
QPen pen(vehicle->Colour());
```